# Help to understand "Making more noise than was wise"?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning

> That third night he found his way more quickly than before. He was walking so fast he knew he was **making more noise than was wise**, but he didn't meet anyone.

I don't understand the structure of "**making more noise than was wise**". I guess it means *if he managed in a wise way, he wouldn't be making so much noise*. But I'm not sure if my understanding is correct. Can someone help to explain its structure and meaning?

-- Excerpted from Harry Potter.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. It would have been `wise`, or `preferable`, in this use, to make less noise... but he was hurrying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct. The excerpt is saying that (Harry Potter, I presume) made his way slowly, carefully, and quietly through the forest on the first two nights. On the third night, however - perhaps because he knew his way through the woods better or perhaps for some other reason - he was tearing through the woods quickly. His foot speed did not allow for him to avoid stepping on noisy branches, etc. His feet met the ground with a heavier thud, like when you're on the second story of a house and you run across the room and you can hear your footsteps much louder. The enchanted forest was a very dangerous place and the only reason his recklessness didn't attract attention from something dark and evil was simply luck.

Comment: Harry was actually trying to find the room where the mirror of Eliesed was put. But I haven't put enough context in my question. Sorry.

Comment: Ah well anyway take the concept and apply it to trapsing about the corridors. Hope my answer was helpful